# Using a save button to save arraylist to .dat file on C:drive

Tags: java, netbeans, save, overwrite

I am having a hard time with saving my file to my C: drive using my save button. My action listener looks like this

```
saveButton.addActionListener(
    new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            File savedFile = new File("C:\\data\\inventory.dat");
            if (savedFile.exists() == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    savedFile.createNewFile();
                    outputText.append("The file has been saved\n");
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(JavaGUIFixed.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if (savedFile.exists() == true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        savedFile.createNewFile();
                        outputText.append("The file already exists\n and has been overwritten\n");
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        Logger.getLogger(JavaGUIFixed.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

The problem I keep running into is

```
Dec 06, 2013 12:14:16 AM javaguifixed.JavaGUIFixed$8 actionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Why is this not saving? Essentially it should be creating the directory as well as the file if it doesn't exist and it should overwrite it if it does.

Answer (score 0):

I did some playing around and got this to work. Below is my code

```
 saveButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    File savedFile = new File("C:\\Users\\kerinr\\Documents\\data\\inventory.dat");
                    if (savedFile.exists() == false) {
                        try {
                            savedFile.createNewFile();

                            outputText.append("The file has been saved\n");
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(JavaGUIFixed.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }

                    } else {
                        if (savedFile.exists() == true) {
                            try {
                                savedFile.createNewFile();
                                outputText.append("The file already exists\n and has been overwritten\n");
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(JavaGUIFixed.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Writer writer = null;

                    try {
                        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                                        new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\kerinr\\Documents\\data\\inventory.dat"), "utf-8"));
                        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++) {
                            writer.write(inventory.get(i).itemName + " \r\n");
                            writer.write(inventory.get(i).inStock + " \r\n");
                            writer.write(inventory.get(i).itemNumber + " \r\n");
                            writer.write(inventory.get(i).unitPrice + " \r\n");
                            writer.write(inventory.get(i).restockingFee + " \r\n");
                            writer.write(inventory.get(i).inventoryValue + " \r\n");

                        }

                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // report
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            writer.close();
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
```

One thing I have noticed though is that the folder "data" has to already be in place. If it is not then it will not save the file.